# Which permission I need for FB_Ignited method fb_feed?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

In this time I implement Facebook Ignited library to my application Public Ads. Facebook connect/login with no problems. But when i want publish customer ad to their facebook timeline everytime I get result:

scope for FB application Email only

```
fb_feed() - Facebook::api() exception caught: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

with scope publish_actions

```
fb_feed() - Facebook::api() exception caught: An unknown error has occurred.
```

Where I make mistake? Which scope permissions are needed for method fb_feed('post')?

Here is my code:

```
$params = array(
    "message" => "Message for customer's friends",
    "link" => "http://www.mywebpage.com/ads/iphone4s/12312",
    "picture" => "http://image.mywebpage.com/lHkOsiH.png",
    "name" => "Sample title for ad",
    "caption" => "www.mywebpage.com",
    "description" => "Sample text of customer ad."
);

try {
    $this->fb_me = $this->fb_ignited->fb_get_me();
} catch(FBIgnitedException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if ($this->fb_me) {
    try {
        $feed_id = $this->fb_ignited->fb_feed('post',null, $params);
    } catch(FBIgnitedException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This required the extended permission publish_stream while doing the authentication in the scope param.

So you need to add the scope publish_stream not just email

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Here is an nice article to see the different scopes and which one is having higher precedence over other

http://globalspin.com/2013/06/publish_stream-vs-publish_actions/

Comment: Thanks, but with additional permission publish_stream i recieved this exception: fb_feed() - Facebook::api() exception caught: An unknown error has occurred.

Comment: So, the problem was in the second parameter of method fb_feed(). When i changed to 'me', the post was sent to timeline but result is now: fb_feed() - Facebook::api() returned an invalid value. :)